# junit test for a method with return type int and parameters as arraylist

Tags: unit-testing, pom.xml, junit4, assert, junit5

The following method checks for all triplets with the given value/sum. I want to write a @Test method for this method that returns an integer and also takes in an arraylist and a variable as parameters. Is there a way I can write a junit5 test for the following code-

```
int triplets(ArrayList<Integer> a, int sum)
{
    int l, r;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 2; i++) {

        l = i + 1;
        r = a.size() - 1;
        while (l < r) {
            if ( a.get(i) + a.get(l) + a.get(r) == sum) {
                count++;
                System.out.print("Triplet " + count +" is " + a.get(i) + ", " + a.get(l) + ", " + a.get(r) + "\n");
                l++;
                r--;
            }
            else if (a.get(i) + a.get(l) + a.get(r) < sum)
                l++;

            else // arr.get(i) + arr.get(l) + arr.get(r) > sum
                r--;
        }
    }
    if(count!=0)
    {
        System.out.print("Total triplets present: " + count);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JUnit5, you could use a ParameterizedTest with a MethodSource for this.

```
static Stream<Arguments> arrayListProvider() {

    List<Arguments> argList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> testList;
    int sum, expectedResult;

    // Repeat this as required to cover the set of test cases of interest
    // Test set 1
    testList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
    sum = 9;
    expectedResult = 1;
    argList.add(arguments(testList, sum, expectedResult));

    // Test set 2
    testList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    sum = 13;
    expectedResult = -1;
    argList.add(arguments(testList, sum, expectedResult));
    //...

    return argList.stream();

}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arrayListProvider")
void testTriplets(ArrayList<Integer> a, int sum, int expectedResult) {

    assertEquals(expectedResult, triplets(a, sum));

}
```